# How can I filter an API?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the MovieDB API and would like to filter it with a search bar. PLEASE HELP ME. I don't even know where to begin. I have to use javaScript/jQuery for the code. I only want to filter it with keywords. :)

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/search/search-movies

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you don't know what an API is. I'll try to give you a little overview.

The movie database api (application programming interface) is a www conform REST (representational state transfer) interface providing methods in an online environment to control the movie database data from external applications.

To learn more about RESTful APIs and what it is please check the following simple explanation for beginners: https://medium.com/extend/what-is-rest-a-simple-explanation-for-beginners-part-1-introduction-b4a072f8740f

So you won't filter the api. What you may want to filter is data received from the api. To do so, you first have to implement the api as described in their documentation. You probably want to filter movies by their keywords. So what you do is you implement some Javascript AJAX Client or similar to request data from the API.

The API now provides a route to request movies by their keyword:

```
GET /keyword/{keyword_id}/movies
```

https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/keywords/get-movies-by-keyword

They also provide a JavaScript / Jquery example for each request within there api documentation.

This would be one way to request already filtered data. But there are obviously different attempts. You could also request all related movies by any filter criteria and filter them using JavaScript on the client side.

All in all I guess you have to start by learning about REST Apis and how to access their Routes using JavaScript.

Here is a helpful guide for starting:

https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-connect-to-an-api-with-javascript/